# AWS CodeDeploy for ECS Fargate Blue/Green

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-fargate

I am following the note:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/use-aws-codedeploy-to-implement-blue-green-deployments-for-aws-fargate-and-amazon-ecs/

I can see new Blue/Green Deployment in ESC-Fargate Service when updating TaskDefinition and Service.

In CodeDeploy, I can see application `AppECS-webapi-docker-cluster-webapi-docker-service2` and deployment ground `DgpECS-webapi-docker-cluster-webapi-docker-service2`

[image]

From Deployment Group, I create a Deployemnt:

[image]

What I should add in appspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The AppSpec file for an Amazon ECS deployment specifies your task definition, container name, and container port."

Please refer to this article for more information - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-ecs-create-appspec-file.html

Comment: Resolved. Still not understand why we need appspec.yml when Deployment Group has the info of ECS service which is linking to Task Definition and Container name and Port?

Answer (score 0):

Base on Aws

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html

For Amazon ECS compute platform applications, the AppSpec file is used by CodeDeploy to determine:

1. Your Amazon ECS task definition file. This is specified with its ARN
   in the TaskDefinition instruction in the AppSpec file.
2. The container and port in your replacement task set where your
   Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer reroutes traffic
   during a deployment. This is specified with the LoadBalancerInfo
   instruction in the AppSpec file.
3. Optional information about your Amazon ECS service, such the
   platform version on which it runs, its subnets, and its security
   groups.
4. Optional Lambda functions to run during hooks that correspond with
   lifecycle events during an Amazon ECS deployment.